# How to wait for a group of goroutines?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

let's say I want to start a group of goroutines and than wait for all of them to finish (e.g. return).
I can think of some channel-based solution (e.g. create a channel and listen to it counting received messages which shall be sent by each of goroutines and quiting after receive corresponding number of msgs) but maybe there's a more elegant/efficient solution because this case seems very common.

Comment: You're correct; it is a common problem. See: [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup)

Answer (score 6):

Yes; you want a [`*sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), which you can use by calling `waitGroup.Add(1)` before starting each task, `waitGroup.Done()` when it finishes, and `waitGroup.Wait()` once you have started everything and want to wait for it all to finish, [like this](http://play.golang.org/p/P44vnUIYZo):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i := 1; i < 3; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) { // ensures each run gets distinct i
            fmt.Println("Sleeping", i, "seconds")
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(i) * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("Slept", i, "seconds")
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All done")
}
```